# Error 91 on Frame Control upon Start Up

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a Microsoft Form 2.0 Frame Control with three option buttons. The name of the Frame Control is `Side`, three option button captions are `X`, `O`, and `Random` with names `xOption`, `oOption`, and `randomSide` respectively.
The code runs fine, except upon startup, if I open Excel and run the program immediately, it will give me an `Error 91`, note that one of the options (`X`, `O`, or `Random`) is already selected. In order to get rid of this error, I need to explicitly select another option, then the error goes away. I don't know why this happens. Here is the sub for the `Frame` Control

```
Public Sub Side_Click()

sideLetter = Side.ActiveControl.Caption
If StrComp(sideLetter, "Random") = 0 Then
    Randomize
    tempRand = Int((Rnd() * 2 + 1))
    If tempRand = 1 Then
        sideLetter = "X"
    Else
        sideLetter = "O"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The Line `sideLetter = Side.ActiveControl.Caption` Is the one causing the issue.  I have not explicitly declared `Side` as a frame control in case that's some helpful information because I'm thinking that the object is already declared just by making the Frame Control. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that `Side.ActiveControl` is actually an object, *before* you read it's Caption:

```
Public Sub Side_Click()
If Not Side.ActiveControl Is Nothing Then
    sideLetter = Side.ActiveControl.Caption
    If StrComp(sideLetter, "Random") = 0 Then
        Randomize
        tempRand = Int((Rnd() * 2 + 1))
        If tempRand = 1 Then
            sideLetter = "X"
        Else
            sideLetter = "O"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anyway to declare a specific frame control as an object? For example declare X variable as a Side Frame Control obj?

Comment: `Dim myFrame As MSForms.Frame`